# SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations in node.js webstorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am very much new to ES6, and have wrote a sample class code in node.js using webstorm ide.

```
'user strict';

class PersonClass {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    sayName() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

let person = new PersonClass('My Name');
person.sayName();
```

When I run the code it displays an error

```
class PersonClass {
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Even though I have installed babel-cli, babel-presets-es2015. How can I fix it.

Comment: "user strict"? This user here apparently not so strict with spelling… ;-P

Comment: @deceze my bad haven't noticed that. Thanks :)

Comment: Also upgrade to Node 6 and this won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, try writing `use strict` instead of `user strict`